# How can I disable the lighttpd daemon on startup in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, lighttpd

I'm setting up lighty according to [this guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-lighttpd-with-php5-php-fpm-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-12.10), and I don't really have an use for the lighttpd daemon that was installed (this is the one that resides in /etc/init.d/lighttpd). I don't want a webserver running all the time, except when I'm working. I want to just call lighttpd -Df lighttpd.conf when I need to.

How can I disable this ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can disable lighttpd on boot with the following command.

```
sudo update-rc.d -f lighttpd remove
```

This is a script which will remove the lighttpd start up script from the following locations:

```
/etc/rc0.d
/etc/rc1.d
/etc/rc2.d
/etc/rc3.d
/etc/rc4.d
/etc/rc5.d
/etc/rc6.d
/etc/rcS.d
```

To re-enable lighttpd you can run the following command:

```
sudo update-rc.d lighttpd defaults
```

Hope that helps

Comment: And what would be the command if you want to put it back into the start sequence? TIA

Comment: Updated the answer with how to add it back again.

Answer (score 4):

Our with systemd:

```
prompt$ sudo systemctl disable lighttpd
```

You may also want to

```
prompt$ sudo systemctl stop lighttpd
```

as disable does not stop any running server.

systemd pretty much falls back to SysV handling and runs a script that does what Oliver mentioned in his answer (as far as I know)

```
Synchronizing state of lighttpd.service with SysV init with
   /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable lighttpd
```

Eventually evaluating

```
$CHROOT /usr/sbin/update-rc.d "$NAME" defaults
$CHROOT /usr/sbin/update-rc.d "$NAME" disable
```

(On a Fedora box when looking)